# Elegant and efficient way to put incoming serial data into structures

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, deserialization

Suppose we have incoming values representing table of known size like this:

```
-  a  b  c
x  06 07 08
y  10 11 12
z  14 15 16
```

but values are arriving from stream/iterator or another serial form, in up-to-down, left-to-right order:

```
- a b c x 06 07 08 y 10 11 12 z 14 15 16
```

Suppose that data arrives from some provider like `newVal = provider.getNext()` and we can't go in reverse direction.

What is the most elegant and efficient (preffer object oriented) way to put incoming data in three structures:

```
top : 0=>a  1=>b  2=>c
left: 0=>x  1=>y  2=>z
data: 0,0=>06  1,0=>07  2,0=>08
      0,1=>10  1,1=>11  2,1=>12
      0,2=>10  1,2=>11  2,2=>12
```

Would it be better to use some switches/delegates or just buffer all data and extract parts wich we need in loops  **(assume that every value has the same type**, let's say integer) ?

Assume that we don't need collect data in proper structure in real time (whole data can be buffered, but I look for efficient solution).

Real world data in this problem is a triple 'maps', each with size about 500x500 readed from .xls file in java poi extension if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

I think that elegance and efficiency depend on the task you are going to run against the data.
In general case it seems to me that the most efficient way is storing the data in raw format (like `060708101112141516`) and assuming that the element size is constant and we know the amount of 'columns', it is always possible to get the pointer to any element knowing its coordinate (row/column name or number).
Each triple map can also be retrieved from such block of data.

But if your tasks are different from getting the elements by their indices, the realization may differ.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

http://www.javaprogrammingforums.com/java-programming-tutorials/696-multi-dimension-arraylist-example.html

a version of "a vector of vectors"